# Deriving a restriction on a, what have I done wrong?

Tags: inequality

Given that $a$ and $b$ are positive numbers, $b<1$, and that $\frac{1000}{a}+\frac{1000}{b}+ab=1110$, find a restriction on $a$.

What I have is that $\frac{1000}{a}+\frac{1000}{b}+ab=1110 \Rightarrow \frac{a+b}{ab}+\frac{ab}{1000}=\frac{111}{100}$

Using AM-GM yields

$\frac{111}{100}=\frac{a+b}{ab}+\frac{ab}{1000} \geq 2\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{1000}} \Rightarrow \frac{12321}{40000} \geq \frac{a+b}{1000} \Rightarrow \frac{12321}{4000} \geq a+b $

Considering the extremes on $b$, I get that $\frac{12321}{4000} < b < \frac{16321}{4000}$. However, I have been told that my answer is wrong. I cannot find the error in my work, what am I doing wrong here?

Also, is there another, better way of solving the initial problem? My next thought is to solve for $b$ in terms of $a$ and put the restriction on that $b < 1$ and solve for $a$...

Comment: Currently looking for a better way to solve, and I cannot think of any.

Comment: You're told that $b < 1$

Comment: Yeah, so do something like $b=(expression in a)<1$, solve for $a$. Not really getting anything.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach:

Multiply both the sides by $ab$ and rearranging:

$b^2a^2 + b(1000 - 1110a) + 1000a = 0$

If the above equation has both the roots positive then both the sum and the product of the roots will be positive.

Sum of the roots $= \frac{(1110a - 1000)}{a^2} > 0 \implies a > \frac{1000}{1110}$

Product of the roots $=\frac{1000}{a} > 0$, which is true for any $a > 0$

Also if we want to make sure that both the roots of the above equation are in $(0,1)$, then we must have the derivative $2a^2b + 1000-1110a = 0$ for some $b$ in $(0,1)$, which means $0 < \frac{1110a - 1000}{2a^2} < 1 \implies a > \frac{1000}{1110} = 0.9009$ and $2a^2 -1110a + 1000 > 0 \implies a^2 - 555a + 500 > 0 \implies a \in (-\infty, 0.90237) \vee (554.10, \infty)$

Finally, combining the two conditions, $a \in (0.9009, 0.90237) \vee(554.10, \infty)$

Comment: Apparently that answer is incorrect; I am going to look for a different way to solve this problem.